# How to select entire word when single click

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to select the entire word when single click? For example, I have a text:

```
I live in central Ave.
```

When I single click the character 't' in word 'central', the whole word 'central' needs to be selected. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "select" ?

Comment: You have to be more specific about that it is you are trying to achieve exactly. The default mechanism in most (maybe all browsers?) is that a double click on a any word will select it. Why would you want to override that? And in exactly what frame of work. Technically it is possible to add a click event listener that takes action but it would require a certain structuring of the way the document is built in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope provided jsfiddle helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/MattCMC/Vap7C/1875/

You can define this as a class click function:

```
  $(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  s = window.getSelection();
  var range = s.getRangeAt(0);
  var node = s.anchorNode;
  while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') != 0) {
    range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
  }
  range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
  do {
    range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);

  }
  while (range.toString().indexOf(' ') == -1 && range.toString().trim() != '');
  var str = range.toString().trim();
  //alert(str);
});
```

Comment: I did some changes, I hope it will help
https://jsfiddle.net/adrxlm/ewbq29m6/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following method. It does require a plugin though, but that would be needed because the selection event is run by the browser and not in-browser code.

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38089/select-text-with-just-one-click

Answer (score 0):

What I am proposing is a workaround. You might have to maintain additional states to deselect. Let me know if that works for you.

HTML

```
<span class="text"> text is all I got </span>
```

JS

```
// find elements
$(function () {
    $('.text').each(function (index, ele) {
        $(ele).html($(ele).text().split(' ').map(function (word) {
            return ['<span class=\'clickable\'>', word, '</span>'].join('')
        }).join(' '))

    })
    $('.clickable').click(function (e) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue').css('color', '#fff')
    })
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/715208/

Answer (score -1):

**It is possible.**

You could use JS to nest each word in a span tag, then bind a click event to the containing element. Use bubbling/capturing to work out which got clicked and append a "highlighted" class which you can style differently to appear highlighted.

Comment: This is so non-elegant though for functionality that is native with a dbl-click already.

Comment: @CodeAt30 your issue is with the problem posed by the original poster, not by the solution which achieves exactly what is required.

Comment: Yes that is correct but I still think it should be mentioned before he goes a head with this solution. Sometimes the proper answer to a question is actually explaining why the methodology which led to the question is problematic. But yes your answer is legit though lacking code example.

Comment: Agreed, which I think is where comments under the original question are more relevant. However we must also accept that we don't have enough context to judge what the use case is, you've assumed select means to make the section copy pastable, whereas it could be used in an ebook reader app to provide a floating tip above a highlighted word.

Comment: Also I didn't provide any code as there wasn't an attempted solution to resolve, I'm not too keen on writing apps for people instead of answering questions. :)